# Separator in Master detail using foreach?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]I need a little help here.

I am working on a mobile application which uses Grial UIKIt. They use simple content page that works like MaterDetail menu. I am trying to get separator between two entries, not the whole list. I am trying to use the boxView as a separator. But it goes like this all over the menu.

```
My Xaml

<!-- MENU ENTRIES -->
            <ListView
                Margin="5,20,0,5"
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="MainListView"
                SelectedItem="{ Binding MainMenuSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay }"
                ItemsSource="{ Binding MainMenuEntries }"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Style="{ StaticResource MainMenuListViewStyle }"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <local:MainMenuItemTemplate />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="boxViewVisible"
                                VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0"
                                Style="{ StaticResource Horizontal1ptLineStyle }"
                                BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }" IsVisible="{Binding isVisible}"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

What i am trying

```
public void isVisible(BoxView boxView)
    {
        foreach (var page in MainListView.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (page is MyArticle)
            {
                boxView.IsVisible  = true;
            }
            else
            {
                boxView.IsVisible = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

this doesn't work and i still have every line separated. I cant access my boxview in my cs as it is in listview it doesnt let me.

Please help me with this.

Edit

```
  public class MenuEntry
            {


                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Icon { get; set; }
                public bool UseTransparentNavBar { get; set; }
                public Type PageType { get; set; }
                public Func<Page> CreatePage { get; set; }
                public Type NavigationPageType { get; set; }
                public bool IsModal { get; set; }
            }
        }

  private void LoadData()
        {
            MainMenuEntries = new List<MenuEntry>();

            //foreach (var cat in Catalog.MenuItemList)
            //{

            MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
            {
                Name = AppResources.A_StringCategory,
                Icon = GrialIconsFont.File,
                CreatePage = () => new ArticleBrowser()
            });

            MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
            {
                Name = AppResources.A_Category,
                Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
                CreatePage = () => new Login()
            });
```

Comment: yes, but only between 2 itrms and the rest without separators

Comment: like gmail does

Comment: entry 
entry 
entry 
entry 
entry 
entry 
---------
entry 
entry

Comment: You cannot access the view in DataTemplate inside cs file, but you can use DataTemplateSelector for this I'll suggest an answer.

Comment: So I should set my visibility in my template view?

Comment: Yes, (Bind the IsVisible) There was no need for TemplateSelectors, I have added an answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean property HasSeparator in your class and Bind it to the IsVisible property of the BoxView.

**Item's class**

```cs
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool HasSeparator { get; set; }
}
```

**Adding Items**

```cs
MasterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>()
{
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "One"},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Two"},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Three", HasSeparator = true},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Four"},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Five", HasSeparator = true},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Six"},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Seven"},
    new MasterPageItem(){Title = "Eight"},
};
```

**Xaml usage**

```cs
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MasterPageItems}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <BoxView
                        BackgroundColor="Gray"
                        HeightRequest="2"
                        IsVisible="{Binding HasSeparator}"
                        VerticalOptions="End" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you mark it as answer if it works for you? @kon